# Right way of adding a tag to a testcase using rally wsapi v2.0

Tags: java, rally

```
           //this will query for the tag, if not found it will create the tag.
            ChkTag(r, wspace_ref, projref, tagx);

            QueryRequest tg = new QueryRequest("Tag");
            tg.setWorkspace(wspace_ref);
            tg.setProject(projref);
            tg.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", tagx));
            QueryResponse resp = r.query(tg);
            if(resp.wasSuccessful()&&resp.getTotalResultCount()==1){
                System.out.println("The tag: "+tagx+" is found.");
            } else {
                System.err.println("The tag wasn't found for this testcase.\n"
                        + "ChkTag() method was run earlier which should have created the tag. something weird is going on...");
            }

            //Now adding the tag to the test case
            JsonArray tiger = new JsonArray();
            tiger.add(resp.getResults().get(0));

            //System.out.println("Updating testcase tags...");
            JsonObject updatedtesttag = new JsonObject();
            updatedtesttag.add("Tags", tiger);

            UpdateRequest updatetag = new UpdateRequest(ref_testcase, updatedtesttag);
            UpdateResponse updatetagresp = r.update(updatetag);

            if(updatetagresp.wasSuccessful())
                System.out.println("Tag successfully added to the test case");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Tag for this testcase is Null...\nSkipping Tag...");
        }
```

I am not sure about this line:

```
tiger.add(resp.getResults().get(0));
```

Is this line going to reset the testcase to only have this one tag, or would this append this one tag to the existing list of tags of the testcase? I don't want to lose existing tags of testcases.

Comment: What you're doing above will definitely just replace the entire collection.  Let me try to dig up an example of adding items to a collection with the java api...

Comment: Then from my understanding, I have to query for tags from the testcase, and keep the tags (jsonarray). Then add my new tag to that json array and finally update testcase with it. Is that right?

Comment: That will work, but will probably be slower and/or require more code.  You should be able to just add to the Tags collection as described here in the WSAPI docs: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/rest_collections.jsp
I couldn't find any code examples to do it though...

Comment: Turns out what I described above wasn't possible with the existing toolkit, so I released a new version.  See answer + example below....

Answer (score 0):

The ability to do this was a long outstanding issue in this project: https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/issues/14

I had some extra time yesterday so I implemented the ability to write to collection endpoints and released a new version (2.2.1) of the toolkit.

Here's an example of doing what you want:

```
//Build the array of tags to add
JsonArray tagRefs = new JsonArray();
JsonObject tagRef = new JsonObject();
tagRef.addProperty("_ref", "/tag/12345");
tagRefs.add(tagRef);

//Update the collection
CollectionUpdateRequest testCaseTagCollectionAddRequest = new CollectionUpdateRequest("/testcase/23456", tagRefs, true);
testCaseTagCollectionAddRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name"));
CollectionUpdateResponse testCaseTagCollectionAddResponse = restApi.updateCollection(testCaseTagCollectionAddRequest);
```

Note you can use the updateCollection method to remove items from a collection as well.

This new functionality just wraps the writable collection endpoints in WSAPI v2.0 as described here: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/rest_collections.jsp